# Magento 2 - Admin Create Order. sales/order_create/loadBlock cant retrieve layout with <script type="text/x-magento-init">

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml, sales-order, ajax

When Creating an order via the admin. the forms are being loaded by
http://localhost/project/Admin/sales/order_create/loadBlock/block/shipping_method,totals,billing_method?isAjax=true

this request will load

```
sales_order_create_load_block_shipping_method.xml
sales_order_create_load_block_totals.xml
sales_order_create_load_block_billing_method.xml
```

reference would be

```
Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\LoadBlock
```

now if I add this line of code to any of those layouts

```
    <block name="sample_block"
           class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
           template="My_Module::order/create/shipping/method/sample.phtml">
         <arguments>
            ........jsLayout args 
         </arguments>

    </block>
```

this will work well if My_Module::order/create/shipping/method/sample.phtml is just a normal html template.

eg.

```
<h1>sample</h1>
```

my problem is when i try to call the jslayout. its not working.

```
<div id="cc-ts-trigger" data-bind="scope:'sample-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "#cc-ts-trigger": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
                }
            }
        </script>
</div>
```

NOTE that the JSlayout is working when refreshing the page(means it was not retrieved via ajax). i tried doing the same in sales_order_create_index.xml and it works so i dont think its a misconfiguration in the layout.

I tried to inspect element after the rendering via ajax. and it stops at

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

like it reads it as a normal html comment.

does anyone experience loading a layout via ajax call? do i need to create a new layout processor for this one or magento already has one.

im also not that knowledgeable on creating layout processors

I just want to load a JSlayout in on a layout.xml thats being called by sales/order_create/loadBlock via ajax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I was also having this issue, specifically the console error below

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at legacy-build.min.js:1
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at String.evalScripts (legacy-build.min.js:1)
at legacy-build.min.js:1
```

The code causing the issue was this (I have removed client-specific details):

```
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "MyClient_Core/js/giftMessage": {
                "myparam1": "my_value_1",
                "myparam2": "my_value_2",
                "myparam3": "my_value_3"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I will say I am not 100% sure what the root cause of the error is, but I suspect once the block has been loaded the JS attempts to evaluate it but does not know how to handle this syntax when loaded.

I updated this to load the component inline like so:

```
<div id="gift_options_giftmessage" class="giftcard-form giftcard-send-form fieldset admin__fieldset"
     data-mage-init='{"MyClient_Core/js/giftMessage": {"myparam1": "my_value_1","myparam2": "my_value_2","myparam3": "my_value_3"}}'>
```

The only real change is adding it within the `data-mage-init` attribute and removing the element specifier (that might not be the right name for it?) as we are referencing the div directly by initialising it inline.